# External User ID to Internal User ID

Tags: security, api, microservices

There is an internal API, REST client over DB,  all of which methods require User ID as parameter. 
User ID is an integer value - numeric PK in User table.

Also there is an public API, that is like a Auth+Proxy Gateway: it checks the JWT token, extract User ID and then redirect to internal API.
So right now  User ID is passed as part of JWT token, so everyone can extract/know it value - the problem that I want to solve.

The thirst what I thought was to change public API to work with an External User ID (GUID for example): 
- add additional mapping table to have mapping between external and internal ID;
- external API  takes external ID from JWT, makes query to retrieve corresponding  internal user ID
- call internal API using internal user ID

What I do not like in this approach is an additional query to DB with each request. Using caching can reduce number of queries, but…

Another option, that I see, is to use JWE token instead of JWT. At least one disadvantage of this approach is the encryption/decryption expenses.

Comment: Did you mean _third_ instead of _thirst_ in the third paragraph? I didn't correct it because I don't see the _first_ and _second_ alternatives being mentioned.

Comment: The encryption + decryption can be neglected on todays hardware. Almost everything runs TLS and its by no means a slowdown. If you are concerned, you can encrypt only the user ID (encrypted ID = public ID). That way you are dealing with only one block of cipher operation. That is totally neglectible.

Comment: What problem are you trying to fix? Ok, so any authenticated user can figure out their primary key in the database. I can see how this might be a security issue. However, replacing it with a GUID would not solve that issue. It simply replaces one ID with another.

Answer (score 0):

> So right now User ID is passed as part of JWT token, so everyone can extract/know it value - the problem that I want to solve.

The JWT should be accessible just by the owner user. So, if you are using HTTPS, only the server and client know JWT value. So, I'm not sure if there is a problem here.

Anyway, the first options sounds better to me (it is the usual way to do it when you are using Oauth2 with third party).

Also, you could create an "intermediate API" which remove the JWT and redirects the requests, but I'm not sure if this approach makes sense on your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

When using the words "internal" and "external" it is often helpful to add the phrase "...with respect to [X]".  I am not clear if your proposed identifier is meant to be external with respect to the web code or if it is external with respect to the database (meaning that the web layer also works with the external ID).

Given the little I know about your situation, I would suggest that you need an identifier that is external with respect to the *database*.  The JWT and all API calls should use this external identifier. And, in addition, all API code that accesses the database should use work with the external ID as well.

The internal ID, an integer/ascending primary key, is an implementation detail that is only meaningful to the database. In most cases you're not going to want to expose that to anything other than the database itself. It's possible, for example, that some day you will wish to switch to a partitioned distributed database and you'll want that identifier to be a GUID instead of an integer so that you can have distributed inserts. If the integer is exposed to the API code, you'll have to rewrite much of the web code.  But if you keep it internal to the database, you'll just need to adjust a small amount of SQL code, and none of the stored procedure parameters would need to be changed-- they could keep using the same old external ID as before.

With this approach you avoid additional calls to the DB; the web code never needs to know the internal ID, so you don't need any calls to retrieve it.  The SQL layer will need one additional join, but if it's just to map an external ID to an internal key, all it will need is a single index seek on a covering index, which will have very low performance impact, much lower than a network round trip.